# Paging not working with list view

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have followed the tutorial [at codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24065/Paging-ListView-With-DataPager?msg=3128355#xx3128355xx), and have stumbled into an issue.

I have a `ListView`, listing all the current members names of my site:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstMembers" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("MemberName") %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:ListView>
```

And a `DataPager` underneath:

```
<asp:DataPager ID="DataPagerProducts" runat="server" PagedControlID="lstMembers"
    PageSize="3" OnPreRender="DataPagerProducts_PreRender">
    <Fields>
        <asp:NumericPagerField />
    </Fields>
</asp:DataPager>
```

I am using the following to bind to the List (As per the tutorial):

```
List<Members> member = new List<Members>();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Page.IsPostBack) return;

    DisplayMembers();
}

private void DisplayMembers()
{
    const string strSql = "SELECT DISTINCT [id], [memberNickname] FROM vwGetMemberDetails ORDER BY [memberNickname]";
    SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(strSql, DataConn.Connect()) { CommandType = CommandType.Text };

    SqlDataReader rdr = sqlComm.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        member.Add(new Members
            {
                MemberId = rdr["id"],
                MemberName = rdr["memberNickname"]
            });
    }

    rdr.Close();
    DataConn.Disconnect();
}

private class Members
{
    public object MemberId { get; set; }
    public object MemberName { get; set; }
}

protected void DataPagerProducts_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lstMembers.DataSource = member;
    lstMembers.DataBind();
}
```

So there are currently 2 numbers on the Pager. But, every time I click 2, the `List` displays nothing, and the `Pager` disappears.

I am usually a frequent worker of the `Repeater` control, and am only using this method as an assumingly 'easier' way.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `model` is not updating in the `DataPagerProducts_PreRender` so it will always display the same dataset already loaded in the page load.

***EDIT***

---

removing `if(Page.IsPostBack) return;` or calling `DisplayMembers()` inside the `DataPagerProducts_PreRender` will work this for me

Comment: Thanks for the insight... Although putting the `DataBind()` in the main method doesnt work either.

Comment: You can follow this tutorial for custom pagination.
http://tutorials.cmsnsoftware.com/2011/07/how-to-use-custom-pagination.html